# cxf logging messages getting truncated

Tags: java, xml, jboss, cxf, wildfly

I have some large xml files that are being logged using cxf logging in jboss. They keep getting cut off with a message that says..

```
ID:2973
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:...
Headers: {}
Messages: (message truncated to 49152 bytes)
```

...

I've looked around here and what I gather is that 49152 is the default max size and I should be able to set some kind of property called "limit" with a value of -1 so it will no longer truncate, but I have absolutely no idea what configuration or property file I need to put that in and where.

We appear to be using wildfly to set various system properties in my standalone-full.xml. We're defining

```
<property name="org.apache.cxf.logging.enabled" value="true"/>
```

I tried adding...

```
<property name="org.apache.cxf.logging.limit" value="-1"/>
```

to my standalone-full.xml file in the system properties section, but that didn't work. There's a number of different loggers defined in the standalone-full.xml as well as in logging.properties file, but I'm not even sure what the exact syntax of this new property would look like or where it goes.

I did not write this code initially, and I do not have access to the original source either so updating a config or property file is all I have to go on. Any thoughts or assistance would be much appreciated.